# Connect to SQL Server with Windows credentials from a Docker container

Tags: sql-server, docker, windows-authentication

On my local Windows machine I connect to a SQL Server database on a local network using Windows credentials (`trusted_connection` in an ODBC connection string).

In a Docker container running Ubuntu, I cannot ping google.com and I cannot ping the server name, but I can ping my IP address, and I can ping the server IP address. All of these pings work from Windows, but not from Docker/Ubuntu.

Is there a way to connect to and query the server, using the trusted_connection / Windows credentials of the computer which is running the Docker container?

Comment: Pinging into and out of Docker containers is a bit of a hairy issue due to the combination of Docker's vNIC behaviours and Windows using ICMP with *nixes often defaulting to pings with UDP or TCP. I'd ignore the pings and concentrate on the Windows authentication problem, e.g.: [Windows authentication in Docker containers just got a lot easier](https://www.axians-infoma.de/techblog/windows-authentication-in-docker-containers-just-got-a-lot-easier/)

Comment: You cannot use Windows Authentication from a non-Windows host (in this case, Ubuntu)

Comment: *"You cannot use Windows Authentication from a non-Windows host (in this case, Ubuntu) "* That isn't true, @gvee , you *can* set up Ad authentication in Linux environments, it's just not simple.